# How to create a huge table of checkboxes (I mean HUGE!)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am busy creating a website where a user has to select some checkboxes from a huge matrix of checkboxes.  100 by 100 = 10 000 boxes to be more specific!

The way I have set out doing this is by creating 100 vertical divs, each with 100 checkboxes in them.

This seems to work OK but it ends up being a HUGE amount of code! So much, that when I hit refresh in Dream Weaver, it crashes!

I'm pretty new at HTML and Javascript.  Is there a better way of doing this??

I included a very small basic example of what I have done

```
<html lang="en"><head><meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
<title>Checkbox No Vertical Space</title>
<style type="text/css">
#aDiv,
#bDiv,
#cDiv{
    float:left;
    width:12px;
}

#aDiv input,
#bDiv input,
#cDiv input{
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
}
</style></head><body>

<div id="aDiv">
    <input type="checkbox" value="a1">
    <input type="checkbox" value="a2">
    <input type="checkbox" value="a3">
    <input type="checkbox" value="a4">
    <input type="checkbox" value="a5">
    <input type="checkbox" value="a6">
</div>

<div id="bDiv">
    <input type="checkbox" value="b1">
    <input type="checkbox" value="b2">
    <input type="checkbox" value="b3">
    <input type="checkbox" value="b4">
    <input type="checkbox" value="b5">
    <input type="checkbox" value="b6">
</div>

<div id="cDiv">
    <input type="checkbox" value="c1">
    <input type="checkbox" value="c2">
    <input type="checkbox" value="c3">
    <input type="checkbox" value="c4">
    <input type="checkbox" value="c5">
    <input type="checkbox" value="a6">
</div>

</body></html>
```

Thanks!

Allan

Comment: For what do you need this? I don't think it will be a very user friendly interface.

Comment: 10k checkboxes? Do you think there might be a better way to arrange your user interface? If Dreamweaver crashes, how do you know you won't crash some poor user's browser?

Comment: You can easily generate this checkbox matrix using DHTML and javascript.

Comment: What ID should the 27th DIV have? `aaDiv`? (There are only 26 letters.)

Comment: **Quote OP:** _"Is there a better way of doing this?"_  Yeah, don't put 10,000 checkboxes on a page!  Maybe you'd share your reasons for this with us.

Answer (score 2):

This code performs well:

```
var i, j, div, cb, frag;

frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
cb = document.createElement( 'input' );
cb.type = 'checkbox';

for ( i = 0; i < 100; i += 1 ) {
    div = document.createElement( 'div' );

    for ( j = 0; j < 100; j += 1 ) {        
        div.appendChild( cb.cloneNode( false ) );
    }    

    frag.appendChild( div );
}

document.body.appendChild( frag );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Kyswa/1/show/

(although my machine has performance issues when scrolling the page)

Comment: +1, I always wondered what 10,000 checkboxes looks like.  I'm using Safari on a PPC Mac which normally has performance issues on everything else... no problems scrolling your demo though.

Comment: Uhhh... this takes 16+ seconds to load on my machine... the jQuery version I posted takes less than 4 seconds. I think this is due to the div's your adding.

Comment: Haha, I was until you asked. Mine takes less than 6 seconds in IE. Although, Sime Vidas is instant in IE. Why is that?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris: Chrome is crazy slow at appending to the DOM.

Comment: So Chrome is slow at appending div's but not checkboxes... ?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris: Hmmm...  I never tried any deeper analysis of Chrome's performance, but it appears that if you're appending nested DOM elements, it takes a major hit. Appending 10,000 divs is quick if there's nothing nested inside.

Comment: MobileSafari does not like that link one bit.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris I've got the same results in Chrome and IE. Funny how different browsers act differently...

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and made a jQuery version of this, and made sure the width was dynamically calculated to ensure that you have 100x100 checkboxes cross browser. I also added some html5 data attributes to the checkboxes, so you wont have to calculate it every time. Also, there's a single event hooked up to a containing div, so events will perform well. Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="checkboxes">
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#checkboxes {
    line-height: 0;
}

#checkboxes input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}​
```

**JavaScript** *+ jQuery 1.7*

```
$(function(){

    var target = $('#checkboxes');

    var x, y, checkbox;
    for(x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        for(y = 0; y < 100; y++)
        {
            checkbox = $('<input></input>', {
                'type': 'checkbox',
                'data-x': x,
                'data-y': y
            });

            target.append(checkbox);
        }
    }

    target.width(checkbox.outerWidth() * 100);

    target.on('change', 'input:checkbox', function(){

        var $this = $(this),
            x = $this.data('x'),
            y = $this.data('y'),
            checked = $this.prop('checked');

        alert('checkbox changed (' + x + ', ' + y + '): ' + checked);
    });

});​
```

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/xixonia/Uq7CU/1/

Here's a fun version where you can draw by moving your mouse over the checkboxes:

http://jsfiddle.net/xixonia/Uq7CU/2/

Answer (score 0):

This may not be proper HTML or follow recommended guidelines, but you could use a `<table></table>`. Get rid of your `<div></div>`'s, make one `<div></div>` with an id of "grid", and add this to your javascript:

```
var grid = "";
grid += "<table>";
for (var row = 0; row < 100; row++)
{
   grid += "<tr>";
   for (var col = 0; col < 100; col++)
   {
      grid += "<td>";
      grid += "<input type='checkbox' value='" + row + "-" + col + "'>";
      grid += "</td>";
   }
   grid += "</tr>";
}
grid += "</table>";
document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = grid;
```

Please let me know if this doesn't work or if it has any errors!

Comment: He already has performance issues... using a `table` with 10,000 cells is just going to make that worse.

Comment: Probably, but it seems better than hand coding it... still not a good solution though.

Comment: @Sparky672 Out of curiosity, what does Sime do different that has performance gains? I'd like to know for future reference.

Comment: That's not what I meant... I'm talking about how the browser renders `table`'s versus `div`'s.

Comment: I would think a table is the semantically correct option here, but when I tried your code in a fiddle in IE7 it locked up the browser for more than a minute: http://jsfiddle.net/cy9bK/, however when I converted it to push the pieces into an array and join them at the end rather than repeatedly concatenating strings it only takes about one second: http://jsfiddle.net/cy9bK/1/

Comment: P.S. @Sparky672 - from the second fiddle in my previous comment it seems that (for IE, at least, and I would imagine other browsers are probably faster) the performance problem isn't in rendering a table with that many cells, the problem is in how the markup is generated in the first place. But one second to generate _and_ render doesn't seem much of a problem to me...

Comment: Okay, so I guess if he chooses to use my method (which I guess not), he should replace string concatenation with array pushing. Why is array pushing faster than string concatenation though, out of curiousity?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to have checkboxes?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>Small Page</title>
<style>
table{layout:fixed;width:95%;margin:0 auto;}
td{border:ridge thin gray;width:1%;font-size:8px;color:white;background-color:white;padding:0}
td:hover{background-color:blue}
input{font-size:smaller}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Boxes<br>
<input type="text" size="20" value=""></h1>

<script>
onload= function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].onclick= function(e){
        e= e || window.event;
        var r= 0, c= 0, row, col,
        who= e.target || e.srcElement,
        msg= document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        if(who.tagName== 'TD'){
            who.style.backgroundColor= 'red';
            msg.value= who.id.replace('r','row: ').replace('c',' col: ');
        }
    }
}
var r= 1, c= 1, str= '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n<tbody>';
while(r<101){
    str+= '\n<tr>';
    c= 1;
    while(c<101){
        str+= '<td id="r'+r+'c'+c+'">x</td>';
        ++c;
    }
    str+= '</tr>';
    ++r;
}
str+='</tbody>\n</table>\n';
document.write(str);
</script>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```